# Probability Integral transformation and distance

Tags: data-transformation

I have transformed multivariate normally distributed data into uniform distribution using the Probability Integral transformation.  Now I want to preserve the locality of the data points, that is, if there were two data points that have the same distance to a given point in the multivariate normally distributed data; then after transformation, is the distance between those two points  and the given point  remains equal in the corresponding uniformly distributed data? If not is there any way to transform data into uniform distribution while keeping data locality?

Comment: They cannot, because you have changed the distances--unless perhaps you mean something unusual by "distance"?  What is your distance function?

Comment: Thank you whuber. But I changed my questions slightly. Using Euclidean  distance, for example, if points a and b have equal distance to point c, after transformation, do the distance  between the  corresponding points a'  and c'  as well as b' and  c'  remain equal?

Comment: The answer of whuber remains the same: no

Answer (score 0):

Answer from comments:

They cannot, because you have changed the distances--unless perhaps you mean something unusual by "distance"? What is your distance function? – whuber

A nonlinear data transformation will always change the distances. You cannot expect to change the distribution and keep the distances. It is just contradictory.